# Reduce interrupt time for different server calls on page load

Tags: google-analytics, page-load-time, asynchronous

I have a page which has several different calls to different analytics api's( Google analytics, facebook analytics) asynchronously.The problems which I am facing is that whenever any response comes from these calls my client starts responding to these calls and this response time I term as interrupt time because during this time my site hangs. Is there any configurable api which handles all these as one parameter and sends me a response only once so that my interrupt time reduces.

Comment: It sounds unlikely that your server would respond to a request a client has made to a third party ressource. It also sounds unlikely that an asychronous call blocks page loading (because that it the problems asynchronous calls where invented to avoid). I can only guess that you talk about some serverside implementation ? Perhaps you can give some more information.

Comment: sorry i wrote the incorrect question . . I have edited the question . .my client responds to third party request and becomes inactive during this time . . .